# Not able to install ADT in Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee, adt, helios

I am using eclipse helios (IDE fo Java EE developers)

and when i am trying to install ADT from Help>Install New Software

i am getting below error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.104.0.v20121024-145224 (org.eclipse.ui 3.104.0.v20121024-145224)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110301-1807]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.2.M20110203-1100]
```

Please help me solving this Conflict.

Comment: Try to remove your existing SDK and ADT and then re install

Comment: I have uninstalled the ADT and DDMS but still I am getting the error while reinstalling it.

Comment: What are you tryig to install?

Comment: ADT and DDMS from Help>Install new software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer docs http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html Eclipse Indigo is the minimum version supported for the 23.0.2 plugin. You would be advised to upgrade your IDE to the latest version.

Comment: Do I have to use Eclipse Indigo instead of Helios?

Comment: No, you should install the latest version which is at least Kepler (K) - it might even be whatever version (L) is, which I know was in beta and might be released by now.

Comment: Tried to update to Kelper but some other error occured while updating....Anyways Thanks for your help..Now I am downloading fresh copy of Eclipse.